Transform Expanding Tablular Data into a Flattened Structure - Excel VBA
I have a expanding table of data that I am looking to convert into a flattened structure so that I can import into a fixed SQL format table. The number of columns will continue to expand as time goes on and what I need to do is reference the ever expanding number of rows when required and columns each month to the output format. For Excel VBA I know that I need the last row and column for the data which is on Sheet1, and that the I will need to loop both the row and column to ultimately push the data to the ending range of the last cells in Sheet2. Samples of Data table structures are below.


This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range or from within sheet
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

Original Data

M Code
let

Change Table name in next line to whatever your actual table name is in Excel
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//Set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Deal", type text}, {"Data", Int64.Type}}
        & List.Transform(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2), each {_, type number})),

//Unpivot all except the first two columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Data", "Deal"}, "Month", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"

Results

